# in react the input value does not change on the change of the select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

the input fields are not getting reset after change of the select

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
     select:"saab",
     inputValues:{},
     input:{'volvo':[1,2,3],'saab':[1,2,3,4],'opel':[1,2,3,4,5],}
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {select,input} = this.state;
    const data = input[select];
    return (
      <div>
       <select value ={this.state.select} onChange={(e)=>{
         console.log(e.target.select)
         this.setState({select:e.target.value, inputValues:{}})
        
         }
         }>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      </select>
        {data.map((a,i)=>{
          return(<input key={i} value={this.state.inputValues[i]} onChange={(e)=>{
            const value = e.target.value
             console.log(i,value)
             this.setState({inputValues:{...this.state.inputValues,[i]:value}})
          }} />)
        })
        }
      {JSON.stringify(this.state.inputValues)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

in the above code i am trying on change of the select function the input value should become empty or reset but its not changing

Comment: Currently this does not look like a [controlled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) as you are not assigning `value` to the select `select`. You need to add `<select value={this.state.select}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working. You should make that after take input values, input update new values. Please don't forget to add solved mark. I share code below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      select: "saab",
      inputValues: {},
      input: { volvo: [1, 2, 3], saab: [1, 2, 3, 4], opel: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }
    };
  }

  changeHandle = () => {
    const currentArrayOfObject = this.state.input;
    currentArrayOfObject[this.state.select] = Object.values(
      this.state.inputValues
    );
    this.setState({ input: { ...currentArrayOfObject } });
  };

  render() {
    const { select, input } = this.state;
    const data = input[select];
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          value={this.state.select}
          onChange={e => {
            console.log(e.target.select);
            this.setState({
          select: e.target.value,
          inputValues: this.state.input[e.target.value]
        });
          }}
        >
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        </select>
        {data.map((a, i) => {
          return (
            <input
              key={i}
              value={this.state.inputValues[i]}
              onChange={e => {
                const value = e.target.value;
                this.setState({
                  inputValues: { ...this.state.inputValues, [i]: value }
                });
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.changeHandle}>save</button>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.input)}
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.inputValues)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this is codebox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-poitras-x52q9?file=/src/App.js:0-1604).

Answer (score 0):

Value of input element ? or the value of this.state.input ?

i think what you meant is to replace the input element's value with the new selected value.

```
{data.map((a,i)=>{
          return(<input value={input[select]} key={i} />)
        })
```

or
if you are talking about emptying the this.state.input

```
 <select onChange={(e)=>{
this.setState({select:e.target.value,input:{...input,[select]:[]}})
}
}>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: i am using dynamic inputs the input fields may change it may 1 input file or 3 input files but on change of the options the input fields should become empty so that the new fields i can particulate for that select box